# Converter in hierarchicaldatatemplate throw nullexcpetion

Tags: c#, xaml

hi my problem is that i need to convert string to uri but i have this error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq62r.png)
my converter:

```
class IsDirectoryToUriConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Uri ImageDirectoryUri { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string,Uri> ImageExtensionTable { get; } = new Dictionary<string,Uri>();



        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            var item = (ArcSharedTreeViewItem)value;
            var data = item.ArcShared;
            if (data.IsDirectory)
            {
                return ImageDirectoryUri; 
            }
            else
            {
                var extension = data.Extension;
                if (ImageExtensionTable.ContainsKey(extension)) return ImageExtensionTable[extension];

                else return ImageExtensionTable["file"];
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

my xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        <converter:IsDirectoryToUriConverter ImageDirectoryUri="Images/folder.png" x:Key="IsDirectoryToImageConverter">
            <converter:IsDirectoryToUriConverter.ImageExtensionTable>
                <system:Uri x:Key="file">Images/file.png</system:Uri>
                <system:Uri x:Key="txt">Images/txt.png</system:Uri>
            </converter:IsDirectoryToUriConverter.ImageExtensionTable>
        </converter:IsDirectoryToUriConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
```

why happen this?

my goal is to create something like this with treeview
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OdVS.png)

Comment: Did you try to debug your converter? Since you get a NullReferenceException the most likely thing is that either 'value' (first line of Convert method) is null or item.ArcShared is null.

Comment: i can't debug because i have error at the beginning

Comment: At the beginning of what?